# error with python launcher unable to find the correct interpreter

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I'm running python 3.3 on mac, and whenever I run a .py file in the terminal window with the command:

```
cd '/Users/Jacob/Desktop/' 
&& '/usr/bin/env pythonw'  '/Users/Jacob/Desktop/PygLatin.py'
&& echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/env pythonw: No such file or directory
```

I've tried using

```
#!/usr/bin/env pythonw
```

on the first line because that was the interpreter that Python launcher had in preferences. It seems like Python launcher is trying to open

```
cd '' && '/sw/bin/pythonw'  '<your script here>'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
```

as the interpreter. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Add `--` after `/Users/Jacob/Desktop/PygLatin.py`

Answer (score 1):

By putting `'/usr/bin/env pythonw'` inside a single quote, you are telling the shell that this is a single filename, with a space in. That's why you're getting the 'No such file' error.

You should use just `/usr/bin/env pythonw` without the quotes.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't clarify I guess, Python Launcher is the one running that command

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to run the file in a wrong way. You can just open the terminal
and type cd [/Your directory here]
and then python yourfile.py
It will search for the interpreter on its own. No need to specify its location(explicitly).

Comment: But what if I want to give my program to someone who'll just use Python Launcher? is there a way I can change the way Python Launcher will access the interpreter?

Comment: There's no need to change how the launcher access the interpreter, the  installation of python will take care of itself, if you'll do this, it may lead to unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interpreter by typing it directly into the INTERPRETER field 
=> The one with the dropdown, but DON'T use the dropdown - TYPE in the path and interpreter)

(Sorry for so many edit - I'm new to this)

On my osx 10.8.5 
On my osx 10.8.5 
 - /usr/bin/pythonw is a 2.7 interpreter 
 - /usr/local/bin/pythonw doesn't exist
 - /usr/local/bin/pythonw3 (and several other) python 3 interpreters are available (I'm using pythonw3.3-32)
 - /sw/bin/pythonw - I don't think it exists

Comment: ok, that helps a lot, actually, that help an unbeievable amount.  The way I fixed it is I have a .command file in the folder with a path to the interpreter, however, I realize that this is a quick fix and it won't work over a large scale.